# Displaying cart item count in custom span tag

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to figure out how to display the current cart count in a span outside of the mini cart. I have tried to add `data-bind="html: getCartParam('subtotal')` into the span but I get an error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "html: function (){return getCartParam('subtotal') }"
Message: getCartParam is not defined`

I am able to add this:

`<?php echo $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getItemsCount(); ?>`

which will give me the cart count but it will break as soon as full page cache is enabled. Is there anyway to accomplish what I want?

EDIT:

```
<?php
$counter = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
?>

<div class="customerInformation">
    <span class="customer-icon contact-phone-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>Call Now <a href="tel:<?php echo $block->getPhoneNumber(); ?>"><?php echo $block->getPhoneNumber(); ?></a>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="/checkout/cart"><span class="lang-icon bag-icon"></span>&nbsp;Bag <span class="badge"><?php echo $counter->getItemsCount(); ?></span></a>
</div>
```

EDIT 2:

`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/customerInformation.phtml`

Comment: please add your full code of phtml file

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya added the content of the file

Comment: please add file path of your custom code.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya added the file path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your block non-cacheable by adding `cacheable="false"` attribute to it in the layout xml:

```
<block name="cart.count" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::cartcount.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
```

I tested it by using the cart helper with FPC on and it appears to do what you want.

**Update:**

Apparently using `cacheable="false"` disables caching for the whole page.

A better way to do it is to get the item count from javascript localStorage. Here's a quick and easy way to do it:

```
<span data-bind="text: JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('mage-cache-storage')).cart.summary_count"></span>
```

Comment: Who knew it would be so easy!

Comment: using cacheable="false" slow down the entire page load speed time.

Comment: I recommend you to use the `customer-data` javascript layer in order to retrieve local-storage information for backward compatibility. Which is already implemented in the `minicart.js` with the `getCartParam('summary_count')` function. Because Magento may change the name of the localStorage key and you may want to refresh the localStorage data from Ajax call with `customerData.reload` function.

Answer (score 1):

Use this knockout code to get the cart count

```
<!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
    <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

apply proper bindings and do add **minicart.js** otherwise the function **getCartParam()** will not be available.

> Refer :
>   vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml