# Magento 2: How to show the number of cart items in a custom phtml using KnockoutJS?

Tags: magento2, cart, uicomponent, knockoutjs, ui

I'm trying to get total number of cart items in my `custom_header.phmtl`. But I'm unbale to get the result.

I've tried using KnockoutJS. I added minicart UI component to my block, which allowed me to display the `summary_count variable`.

*My XML looked something like this:*

```
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_header" as="custom_header" template="Magento_Theme::html/custom_header.phtml" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="my-item-count" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
```

And in my `custom_header.phtml` file I added these two codes,

so I can get summary count:

```
  <span id="HeaderCartBadge" data-bind="scope:'my-item-count'">
      <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
  </span>

  <script type="text/x-magento-init">
      {
          "#HeaderCartBadge": {
              "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
          }
      }
  </script>
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart" component.
```

Do I need to extend `minicart.js` file or something else. Please help me out as I'm new in it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your block non-cacheable by adding `cacheable="false"` attribute to it in the layout xml:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_header" as="custom_header" template="Magento_Theme::html/custom_header.phtml" before="-" cacheable="false">
```

get the item count from javascript localStorage. Here's a quick and easy way to do it:

```
<span data-bind="text: JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('mage-cache-storage')).cart.summary_count"></span>
```

Ref - [Click](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161710/displaying-cart-item-count-in-custom-span-tag)

Comment: Thanks. But I want to show item count using KnockoutJs.